# Menuzord Menu Link Issue

Tags: javascript, html

I am mainly a designer and write some HTML and CSS but am not that good at javascript which I am almost sure is causing the issue that I am having.  I have a client that is working with a template that is using a Menuzord Menu.  It is a one-page layout and they would like one of the links on the main nav to link to another website outside the current site.  I coded the link to link out, but the link does not work.  Any help would be appreciated.

This is the link to the site...http://raycomdigital.us/medplexmd/

Here is the code:

```
  <header id="header" class="header">
    <div class="header-nav navbar-fixed-top header-dark navbar-white navbar-transparent bg-transparent-1 navbar-sticky-animated animated-active">
      <div class="header-nav-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
          <nav id="menuzord-right" class="menuzord orange no-bg"> <a class="menuzord-brand pull-left flip" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="images/logo-wide.png" alt=""></a>
            <ul class="menuzord-menu onepage-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#services">Our Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#questions">Questions</a></li>
              <li><a href="#forms">Forms</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://apps.medplexmdinjury.com/cases/" target="_blank">Portal</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

I need the "Portal" item to link out.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is likely an event listener that is preventing the default click handler from triggering. You could try to read the docs for Menuzord or you could move that hyperlink outside of the `<ul>` so it won't be affected.

Comment: I looked at the documentation but it does not address linking out.  I want to avoid taking it out because of the hover animations associated with the menu items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is likely an event listener that is preventing the default click handler from triggering.

A quick fix for this is to add an `onclick` property which would take precedence over a listener that is attached to a parent element.

```html
<header id="header" class="header">
    <div class="header-nav navbar-fixed-top header-dark navbar-white navbar-transparent bg-transparent-1 navbar-sticky-animated animated-active">
      <div class="header-nav-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
          <nav id="menuzord-right" class="menuzord orange no-bg"> <a class="menuzord-brand pull-left flip" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="images/logo-wide.png" alt=""></a>
            <ul class="menuzord-menu onepage-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#services">Our Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#questions">Questions</a></li>
              <li><a href="#forms">Forms</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a id="portal" href="https://apps.medplexmdinjury.com/cases/" target="_blank">Portal</a></li>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                var portal = document.getElementById('portal');
                portal.onclick = function() {
                  var win = window.open(portal.href, portal.target);
                  win = null;
                }
              </script>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```